# Trying to show element based on whether or not a specific input field has focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As the title says, I'm trying to figure out how I can show a element based on whether or not a input field has focus our not.

So when the specific input field has focus I need to show a element, and when it has no focus the element should be hidden.

I've tried a lot of different things, and this is my lates try:

```
    <script>
     $(".only-oslo-delivery").hide();

     if ($("#address_city").is(":focus")) {
      $(".only-oslo-delivery").show();
     };
    </script>
```

only-oslo-delivery is a < p > tag with the text I want to display when the input field has focus.

address_city is the ID of the input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only runs once, you need event handler to execute it as per user actions:

```js
$("#address_city").on('focus', function() {
  $(".only-oslo-delivery").show();
}).on('blur', function() {
  $(".only-oslo-delivery").hide();
})
```

```css
.only-oslo-delivery {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="address_city">
<p class="only-oslo-delivery">test</p>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know I needed blur as well. I'm very new to jquery/javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind events to your button to show/hide the `.only-oslo-delivery` element when it is focused and blurred.

```
$('#address_city').focus(function() {
  $('.only-oslo-delivery').show();
}).blur(function() {
  $('.only-oslo-delivery').hide();
});
```

Interestingly if the elements are next to each other on the page you could use adjacent css rules to accomplish this without any javascript.

```
<input type="text" id="address_city">
<p class="only-oslo-deliver">...</p>
```

And then use the following css:

```
.only-oslo-delivery {
   display: none;
}
#address_city:focus~.only-oslo-delivery {
   display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="address_city">
<p class="only-oslo-delivery">test</p>

.only-oslo-delivery {
  display: none;
}

$("#address_city").on('focus', function() {
  $(".only-oslo-delivery").show();
}).on('blur', function() {
  $(".only-oslo-delivery").hide();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `focus` event to show and `blur` to hide:

```js
$("#address_city").on('focus blur', function(e) {
  $(".only-oslo-delivery").toggle($('#address_city').is(':focus') && e.type === 'focus');
});
```

```css
.only-oslo-delivery {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='address_city'>
<p class='only-oslo-delivery'>only-oslo-delivery</p>
```

`.toggle(true/false)` would show when `true` and hide when `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
var $field = $('#address_city');
var $info = $('.only-oslo-delivery').hide();

$field.on('focus blur', function (e) {
  $info.toggle(e.type === 'focus');
});
```